# Подключение драйвера pdo mysql ubuntu 16.10

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo, php-fpm

1. Установил apache, php, php-fpm, mysql-client/server, актуальные версии.
2. Раскоментировал в php.ini строку

   extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

В итоге появилась ошибка на сайте:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' not found in
```

Можно какой-то мини гайд как поставить pdo mysql на ubuntu 16.10?

Comment: можно попробовать рестартануть и пхп и апач

Comment: service apache2 restart, апач рестартил, как пхп ребутнуть?

Comment: Было бы конечно интересно узнать как именно устанавливали всё

Comment: apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-fastcghi php.7.0 php7.0-fpm mysql-client-5.7 mysql-server-5.7
И в конфигах апача подрубил php через регулярку

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql (или php7.0-mysql)

sudo service apache2 restart (или sudo service php7.0-fpm restart для nginx/php-fpm 7.0 может и не нужно)
```

**Файлы конфигурации править не нужно!**

Comment: E: Не удалось найти пакет pdo-mysql

Comment: sudo apt-get update

Comment: потом еще раз попробывать

Comment: попробовал, также ошибка

Comment: переустановите еще раз: sudo apt-get install php-mysql

Comment: тоже самое выходит :(

Comment: есть только dll, расскоментировал

Comment: значит вы не тот файл нашли

Comment: Почти правильно. `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` (или `php7-mysql`), `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: Файлы ни какие не трогать!

Comment: пакета `pdo-mysql` в `debian` дистрибутивах нет! `php7-mysql` -> `php-mysql` или `php7.0-mysql` (http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php/php-mysql)

Comment: php7.0-mysql  ...